# wasm rust base 64 support

Tags: rust, base64, webassembly, envoyproxy

I've created a program which works as expected:

```rust
extern crate base64;
```

```rust
// decode base64
let bytes = base64::decode(res[1]).unwrap();
```

```
[dependencies]
base64 = "0.13.0"
serde_json = "1.0.64"
```

When I add this code to Webassembly for an Envoy filter with [base64](https://github.com/marshallpierce/rust-base64) lib , I get the error:

```
INFO: From Compiling Rust cdylib filter (1 files):
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `base64`
 --> filter.rs:1:1
  |
1 | extern crate base64;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
```

[This playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0c35aedad9fa221bdf8b2605e524d040) works with the default "Run" button, but [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a5b5e39660a5db8730e23545c4407600) doesn't work if you run it as "Wasm". You will get the error which described above. Both links have the *exact same code*.

my cargo.toml look like following

```
[dependencies]
base64 = "0.13.0"
serde_json = "1.0.64"
serde = { version = "1.0.126", features = ["derive"] }
```

It seems that web-assemble rust doesn't support `base64` lib (as far as **I understand it** as I'm new to Rust)
**My question:**  which options I have to overcome this issue ?**

> How to reproduce the full scenario (quite simple with the following
> steps)

Download `wasme` (which generate a rust project)

curl -sL https://run.solo.io/wasme/install | sh

```
Init skeleton project
```

`wasme init ./new-filter  ---> choose rust`

Add to the `filter.rs` file the base64 code

```
Run the build
```

`wasme build rust -t mytest .  (needs docker)`

More info about `wasme` etc could be found [here](https://docs.solo.io/web-assembly-hub/latest/tutorial_code/getting_started/)

And you will see the error which I provided above and is the same as the run the playground with WASM

If something is missing or isn't clear please let me know and I'll add

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem, but by default `base64` relies on the standard library which might make it incompatible with WASM. You can turn that off in your `Cargo.toml` by putting `base64 = { version = "0.13.0", features = [] }` instead of `base64 = "0.13.0"`. Hope that's it.

Comment: @isaactfa - thanks! I try it out and I got the same error , do you have any other idea how can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an issue with the base64 crate itself; I've been able to use it both in a Rust project targeting browser (via wasm-bindgen) and in a project creating an envoy filter (using the proxy-wasm-rust-sdk crate).

I think the issue you are experiencing has to do with the way dependencies are declared in wasme specifically - see the autogenerated BUILD file in your project, you might need to adjust it.
(And the solo.io folks often provide focused help at their wasm slack channel.)